# D3.min not returning min value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Trying to use D3.js min function to log the smallest number from an array of numbers. The following array logs 10.42 instead of 5.31.

```
var data = ["5.31", "5.31", "5.32", "6.08", "6.08", "6.08", "6.71", "6.71", "7.34", "7.35", "7.35", "7.96", "7.96", "7.96", "7.97", "9.43", "9.43", "9.44", "9.44", "9.44", "9.92", "9.92", "9.92", "9.92", "9.93", "9.93", "10.42", "10.42", "10.9", "10.9", "10.91", "10.91", "10.91", "11.98", "12.62", "12.62", "12.62", "14.08", "15.04", "16.02", "17.09", "17.09", "17.09", "18.06", "18.45", "19.42", "20", "21.45", "24.85", "26.3"];

console.log(d3.min(data)); // logs 10.42
```

A live version is on [this](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/bGwRdNY) codepen.

Comment: You're comparing strings, the `10.42` is the min, starting with `1`. But try using `d3.min(data, d => parseFloat(d))`

Comment: Thanks Xavier! I didn't realize it was an array of strings not floats.